# Color codes for the arduino touchscreen

Tags: arduino

Is there a table of codes for all the colors for the TFT touchscreen ? Currently I do not know how the code for the color works. I have something like this: http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm  Is there a table of hex codes like :

```
   BLACK   0x0000
   BLUE    0x001F
   RED     0xF800
   GREEN   0x07E0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screen is most likely using the RGB565 (16-bit color) specification instead of what you're used to, RGB888 (24-bit color).

RGB888 simply means:

- red - 8 bit (0-255)
- green - 8 bit (0-255)
- blue - 8 bit (0-255)

RGB565 means:

- red - 5 bit (0-31)
- green - 6 bit (0-63)
- blue - 5 bit (0-31)

Common color definitions for RGB565 are:
(from http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library/coordinate-system-and-units)

```
BLACK    0x0000
BLUE     0x001F
RED      0xF800
GREEN    0x07E0
CYAN     0x07FF
MAGENTA  0xF81F
YELLOW   0xFFE0 
WHITE    0xFFFF
```

Try looking for other RGB888 to RGB565 converters for what you're working with.

To manually "downgrade" your colors, is just pick one you want (from your linked chart), convert your hex value to RGB (888) using a tool (google hex to rgb), then use a function like this:

```
((r / 8) << 11) | ((g / 4) << 5) | (b / 8)
```